# How to know the time elapsed from a specific point of time in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I need to know how much time has been elapsed starting from a certain point using a function to active the timer and use an if statement which becomes true when time has passed. For eg: `if pygameStartTimer > 2000`

`pygame.time.get_ticks` gives the time elapsed from the start of execution of the code which is not what I want. How do I it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pygame.time.get_ticks` just returns a value which represent the time. You can compute the difference of 2 times:

```py
start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

```py
current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
delta_time = current_time - start_time
```

You can also use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` to calculate a point in time in the future:

```py
current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
pygameStartTimer = current_time + 2000
```

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if current_time > pygameStartTimer:
        # [...]
```